# Concatenate two audio files in Swift and play them

Tags: swift, audio, concatenation, avaudioplayer, wav

I try to concatenate .wav audio files in swift.

Here is my code :

```
func merge(audio1: NSURL, audio2:  NSURL) {


    var error:NSError?

    var ok1 = false
    var ok2 = false


    var documentsDirectory:String = paths[0] as! String

    //Create AVMutableComposition Object.This object will hold our multiple AVMutableCompositionTrack.
    var composition = AVMutableComposition()
    var compositionAudioTrack1:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())
    var compositionAudioTrack2:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())

    //create new file to receive data
    var documentDirectoryURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first! as! NSURL
    var fileDestinationUrl = documentDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("resultmerge.wav")
    println(fileDestinationUrl)


    var url1 = audio1
    var url2 = audio2


    var avAsset1 = AVURLAsset(URL: url1, options: nil)
    var avAsset2 = AVURLAsset(URL: url2, options: nil)

    var tracks1 =  avAsset1.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)
    var tracks2 =  avAsset2.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)

    var assetTrack1:AVAssetTrack = tracks1[0] as! AVAssetTrack
    var assetTrack2:AVAssetTrack = tracks2[0] as! AVAssetTrack


    var duration1: CMTime = assetTrack1.timeRange.duration
    var duration2: CMTime = assetTrack2.timeRange.duration

    var timeRange1 = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, duration1)
    var timeRange2 = CMTimeRangeMake(duration1, duration2)


    ok1 = compositionAudioTrack1.insertTimeRange(timeRange1, ofTrack: assetTrack1, atTime: kCMTimeZero, error: nil)
    if ok1 {

        ok2 = compositionAudioTrack2.insertTimeRange(timeRange2, ofTrack: assetTrack2, atTime: duration1, error: nil)

        if ok2 {
            println("success")
        }
    }

    //AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough => concatenation
    var assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)
    assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeWAVE
    assetExport.outputURL = fileDestinationUrl
    assetExport.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({
        switch assetExport.status{
        case  AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Failed:
            println("failed \(assetExport.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Cancelled:
            println("cancelled \(assetExport.error)")
        default:
            println("complete")
            var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
            audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileDestinationUrl, error: nil)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer.play()
        }

    })

}
```

And get this error in the terminal (running on a iPhone) :

*file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3F49D360-B363-4600-B3BB-EE0810501910/Documents/resultmerge.wav*

*success*

**failed Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11838 "Opération interrompue" UserInfo=0x174269ac0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Opération interrompue, NSLocalizedFailureReason=L’opération n’est pas prise en charge pour ce contenu multimédia.}**

But I don't know why I'm getting this error. I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :) Unfortunately, I got the same error with         `assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A`

Comment: Do we know if there is a way to make one file louder than the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got your code working by changing two things:

- the preset name: from `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough` to `AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A`
- the output file type: from `AVFileTypeWAVE` to  `AVFileTypeAppleM4A`

Modify your `assetExport` declaration like this:

```
var assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)
assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A
```

then it will properly merge the files.

*It looks like `AVAssetExportSession` only exports M4A format and ignores other presets. There may be a way to make it export other formats (by subclassing it?), though I haven't explored this possibility yet.*

Comment: Well, it's working one time. If I do it again, I have the same issue as before. Indeed, if I delete the app, it's working again one time and then stop working.

Comment: I have the **failed Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11838...** error again. I'm like I don't know why, but I found out how to solve this problem by erasing the old audio file.

Comment: I seriously think this error happening the second time has nothing to do with the audio conversion itself, but rather with your file management...

Comment: Oops, just saw your new edit/answer. Thanks for posting this clarification. :)

Comment: Do we know if there is a way to make one file louder than the other?

Comment: Is there a way to merge files without converting the audio to the compressed m4a format? I'd like to process the appended audio files for something that requires the raw format.

Answer (score 11):

for swift 3.0 - 
credit goes to **@Peyman** (with light modification)

```
var mergeAudioURL = NSURL()

func mergeAudioFiles(audioFileUrls: NSArray) {
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()

    for i in 0 ..< audioFileUrls.count {

        let compositionAudioTrack :AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())

        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: (audioFileUrls[i] as! NSURL) as URL)

        let track = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0]

        let timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: CMTimeMake(0, 600), duration: track.timeRange.duration)

        try! compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: track, at: composition.duration)
    }

    let documentDirectoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first! as NSURL
    self.mergeAudioURL = documentDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("FinalAudio.m4a")! as URL as NSURL

    let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)
    assetExport?.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A
    assetExport?.outputURL = mergeAudioURL as URL
    assetExport?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler:
        {
            switch assetExport!.status
            {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed:
                print("failed \(assetExport?.error)")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.cancelled:
                print("cancelled \(assetExport?.error)")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.unknown:
                print("unknown\(assetExport?.error)")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.waiting:
                print("waiting\(assetExport?.error)")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.exporting:
                print("exporting\(assetExport?.error)")
            default:
                print("Audio Concatenation Complete")
            }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I needed to merge multiple audio files so I rewrote the function to accept an array of NSURLs. Thought I'd share it here.

I'm new to Swift, so please leave feedback.

Give credit where credit is due: @Eric D. @Pierre Louis Bresson

Here is the code:

```
func mergeAudioFiles(audioFileUrls: NSArray, callback: (url: NSURL?, error: NSError?)->()) {

// Create the audio composition
let composition = AVMutableComposition()

// Merge
for (var i = 0; i < audioFileUrls.count; i++) {

    let compositionAudioTrack :AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())

    let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: audioFileUrls[i] as! NSURL)

    let track = asset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)[0]

    let timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: CMTimeMake(0, 600), duration: track.timeRange.duration)

    try! compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, ofTrack: track, atTime: composition.duration)
}

// Create output url
let format = NSDateFormatter()
format.dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"
let currentFileName = "recording-\(format.stringFromDate(NSDate()))-merge.m4a"
print(currentFileName)

let documentsDirectory = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
let outputUrl = documentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(currentFileName)

// Export it
let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)
assetExport?.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A
assetExport?.outputURL = outputUrl

assetExport?.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({ () -> Void in
    switch assetExport!.status {
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Failed:
            callback(url: nil, error: assetExport?.error)
        default:
            callback(url: assetExport?.outputURL, error: nil)
    }
})

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code, to be place after **println(fileDestinationUrl)** :

```
var file = "resultmerge.m4a"
var dirs : [String] = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String])!
var dir = dirs[0] //documents directory
var path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file)
var pathURLarray:Array = (NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)!).pathComponents!
var pathURL:String = ""
var final = ""
var debut = ""

for i in 1...(pathURLarray.count-1) {
if i == pathURLarray.count-1 {
final = ""
} else {
final = "/"
}
if i == 1 {
debut = "/"
} else {
debut = ""
}
pathURL = debut + pathURL + (pathURLarray[i] as! String) + final
}

var checkValidation = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
if checkValidation.fileExistsAtPath(pathURL) {
    println("file exist")
    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(fileDestinationUrl, error: nil) {
        println("delete")
    }
} else {
    println("no file")
}
```

With this and @Eric D. answer, it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Just to help someone else to "concatenate" I've changed also

```
var timeRange2 = CMTimeRangeMake(duration1, duration2)
```

into

```
var timeRange2 = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, duration2)
```

(besides @Eric D. @Pierre Louis Bresson code).

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you want it to be processed synchronously just add a dispatch

```
var errorExport = true
    //AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough => concatenation
    var assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)
    assetExport.outputFileType =  AVFileTypeAppleM4A
    assetExport.outputURL = fileDestinationUrl
    let sessionWaitSemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)

    assetExport.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({
        switch assetExport.status{
        case  AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Failed:

           println("failed \(assetExport.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Cancelled:

          println("cancelled \(assetExport.error)")
        default:
            //
            errorExport = false
        }

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sessionWaitSemaphore)
        return Void()

    })

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sessionWaitSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

    return errorExport
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 2.1:

```
class func getDocumentsDirectory() -> NSString {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as [String]
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}

class func getFileURL() -> NSURL {
    let audioFilename = getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("\(NSDate()).m4a")
    let audioURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioFilename)

    return audioURL
}

func merge(audio1: NSURL, audio2:  NSURL) {

    finalURL = ProcessViewController.getFileURL()

    let preferredTimeScale : Int32 = 100

    //This object will be edited to include both audio files
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()

    //Song 1 setup
    let compositionAudioTrack1:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())
    let url1 = audio1
    let avAsset1 = AVURLAsset(URL: url1, options: nil)
    let tracks1 =  avAsset1.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)
    let assetTrack1:AVAssetTrack = tracks1[0]
    let duration1: CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(trimmedLength1, preferredTimeScale)
    let startCMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Double(startTime1), preferredTimeScale)
    let timeRange1 = CMTimeRangeMake(startCMTime, duration1)

    //Song 2 setup
    let compositionAudioTrack2:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())
    let url2 = audio2
    let avAsset2 = AVURLAsset(URL: url2, options: nil)
    let tracks2 =  avAsset2.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)
    let assetTrack2:AVAssetTrack = tracks2[0]
    let duration2: CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(trimmedLength2, preferredTimeScale)
    let startCMTime2 = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Double(startTime2), preferredTimeScale)
    let timeRange2 = CMTimeRangeMake(startCMTime, duration1)


    //Insert the tracks into the composition
    do {

        try compositionAudioTrack1.insertTimeRange(timeRange1, ofTrack: assetTrack1, atTime: kCMTimeZero)

        try compositionAudioTrack2.insertTimeRange(timeRange2, ofTrack: assetTrack2, atTime: duration1)


    } catch {

        print(error)

    }

    //Perform the merge
    let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)
    assetExport!.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A
    assetExport!.outputURL = finalURL
    assetExport!.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({
        switch assetExport!.status{
        case  AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Failed:
            print("failed \(assetExport!.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Cancelled:
            print("cancelled \(assetExport!.error)")
        default:
            print("complete")

            self.initializeAudioPlayer()

        }

    })

}
```