# Audio from merge not working

Tags: ios, swift

I used this as a reference: [Concatenate two audio files in Swift and play them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30479403/concatenate-two-audio-files-in-swift-and-play-them)

I'm trying to create an alarm clock, due to restrictive Apple Policy you cannot execute code in the bg past 10 minutes, if I opt out of bg modes and leave my app in the foreground the "sound" suspends if the user clicks the home button, I need the sound to go on until the user does something. UILocalNotifs don't work due to silent/do not disturb buttons. So I want to run a blank audio until the alarm time and then play sound.

So I used the following to run it:

This is what happens when the save button is clicked (user has selected alarm time)

```
 let seconds = Double(comp.second)
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody = "testBody"
    notification.fireDate = dueDatePicker.date
    notification.alertTitle = "testTitle"
    println("seconds:\(seconds)")



    var results:NSArray = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)!

     let audioURL1 = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("alarm", withExtension: "m4a")!
    let audioURL2 = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("music", withExtension: "mp3")!
    println(audioURL1)
    println(audioURL2)
    println(task.uuid)

           mergeAudio2(audioURL1, audioURL2: audioURL2, time: seconds, uuid: task.uuid)
```

and this is the merge audio portion:

```
func mergeAudio2(audioURL: NSURL, audioURL2: NSURL, time:Double, uuid:String) {
    var error:NSError?

    var ok1 = false
    var ok2 = false


    //var documentsDirectory:String = paths[0] as! String

    //Create AVMutableComposition Object.This object will hold our multiple AVMutableCompositionTrack.
    var composition = AVMutableComposition()
    var compositionAudioTrack1:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())
    var compositionAudioTrack2:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())

    //create new file to receive data
    var documentDirectoryURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first! as! NSURL
    var fileDestinationUrl = documentDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("resultmerge.wav")
    println(fileDestinationUrl)

    var file = "resultmerge.m4a"
    var dirs : [String] = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String])!
    var dir = dirs[0] //documents directory
    var path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file)
    var pathURLarray:Array = (NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)!).pathComponents!
    var pathURL:String = ""
    var final = ""
    var debut = ""

    for i in 1...(pathURLarray.count-1) {
        if i == pathURLarray.count-1 {
            final = ""
        } else {
            final = "/"
        }
        if i == 1 {
            debut = "/"
        } else {
            debut = ""
        }
        pathURL = debut + pathURL + (pathURLarray[i] as! String) + final
    }

    var checkValidation = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if checkValidation.fileExistsAtPath(pathURL) {
        println("file exist")
        if NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(fileDestinationUrl, error: nil) {
            println("delete")
        }
    } else {
        println("no file")
    }

    var url1 = audioURL
    var url2 = audioURL2


    var avAsset1 = AVURLAsset(URL: url1, options: nil)
    var avAsset2 = AVURLAsset(URL: url2, options: nil)

    var tracks1 =  avAsset1.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)
    var tracks2 =  avAsset2.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)

    var assetTrack1:AVAssetTrack = tracks1[0] as! AVAssetTrack
    var assetTrack2:AVAssetTrack = tracks2[0] as! AVAssetTrack


    var duration1: CMTime = assetTrack1.timeRange.duration
    var duration2: CMTime = assetTrack2.timeRange.duration

    var timeRange1 = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, duration1)
    var timeRange2 = CMTimeRangeMake(duration1, duration2)


    ok1 = compositionAudioTrack1.insertTimeRange(timeRange1, ofTrack: assetTrack1, atTime: kCMTimeZero, error: nil)
    if ok1 {

        ok2 = compositionAudioTrack2.insertTimeRange(timeRange2, ofTrack: assetTrack2, atTime: duration1, error: nil)

        if ok2 {
            println("success")
        }
    }

    //AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough => concatenation


    var assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)
    assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A
    assetExport.outputURL = fileDestinationUrl
    assetExport.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({
        switch assetExport.status{
        case  AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Failed:
            println("failed \(assetExport.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Cancelled:
            println("cancelled \(assetExport.error)")
        default:
            println("complete")
            var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
            AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
            //audioPlayer.delegate = self

            audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileDestinationUrl, error: nil)
            println(fileDestinationUrl)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer.play()
        }

    })


}
```

The app loads up and everything fine, I get the println's of the files and I get the no file, success and completed print out meaning it all executes. But no sound plays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But no sound plays

Because `audioPlayer` is a local variable and dies before it has a chance to play anything. Promote it to be an instance variable so that it persists.